# Creating Singleton Object from a class in Scala

Tags: scala

When I was playing with the Scala, I couldn't figure out something. Maybe I am doing completely wrong.

I was trying with Rational Example and Complex Example but I couldn't find a way to use operations like R*3/5 and 1/2*R

here is the complex numbers example I am working on

```
class Complex(val real : Int, val img : Int){

  def this(real: Int) = this(real, 0)

  def *(that : Complex) = {
    val realPart = this.real * that.real + -(this.img * that.img)
    val imgPart = this.real * that.img + this.img * that.real
    new Complex(realPart, imgPart)
  }

  override def toString = this.real  + "+" + this.img + "i"

}

object Complex {
  def apply(real : Int, img : Int) = new Complex(real, img)
  def apply(real : Int) = new Complex(real)
}

object ComplexNumbers {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    import ComplexConversions._
    println(Complex(1,2)) // 1+2i
    println(I*2) //0+2i
    println(2*I) //0+2i
  }
}
```

Well I have tried to create an object I

```
object I{
  def apply() = new Complex(0,1)  

  def *(that : Complex) = {
    val realPart = 0 * that.real + -(1 * that.img)
    val imgPart = 0 * that.img + 1 * that.real
    new Complex(realPart, imgPart)
  }
}
```

but it did work for the I*2. but I have problems for 2*I. How can I reach the result that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call "`I * 2`", scala looks for a method named "`*`" on the class of `I`, and finds it.

When you call "`2 * I`", scala looks for a method named "`*`" on the class of `2` (which is [Int](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/index.html#scala.Int)), and cannot find one.

Even though `Int` is defined externally, you can add this method to it in Scala via the "implicit conversion" mechanism. This is covered briefly in [the "implicits" example](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/227.html) and in more detail elsewhere, e.g. [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch01s11.html)

Try adding some code like the following to your "Complex" object:

```
object Complex {
  implicit class IntOps(x: Int) {
    def *(y: Complex) = y * x
  }
}
```

You'll also need to declare I as a val, rather than an Object for this to work:

```
val I = Complex(0, 1)
```

(or add an implicit method like `class Complex { def *(i: I) = ... }`, but that's much uglier)

(I assume by Complex Example, you mean [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/224.html)?)

---

## Working code:

```
class Complex(val real : Int, val img : Int){

  def this(real: Int) = this(real, 0)

  def *(that : Complex) = {
    val realPart = this.real * that.real + -(this.img * that.img)
    val imgPart = this.real * that.img + this.img * that.real
    new Complex(realPart, imgPart)
  }

  override def toString = this.real  + "+" + this.img + "i"

}

object Complex {
  def apply(real : Int, img : Int) = new Complex(real, img)
  def apply(real : Int) = new Complex(real)

  val I = Complex(0, 1)

  implicit def toComplex(x: Int): Complex = new Complex(x)
}

object ComplexNumbers {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    import Complex._

    println(Complex(1,2)) // 1+2i
    println(I*2) //0+2i
    println(2*I) //0+2i
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand the lookup for method part. I added the code but I still get type mismatch error because I doesn't behave like Complex. (it says I.type)?

Comment: The problem is that by declaring "I" as an "object", it gets its own singleton class, which is a different class to Complex. You haven't added "extends Complex" to "I", so it isn't even a complex number. I have added a fully working example to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to use `2*I`, you will need to add a new `*` override for the `Int` class (since `*` is really a method of the class `Int`, meaning `2*I` is really `2.*(I)`).

You can accomplish this with an implicit class:

```
scala> case class myInt(i: Int){
     | def mult(that: Int): myInt = myInt(that * i)
     | }
defined class myInt

scala> implicit class intOverride(i: Int){
     |     def *(that: myInt): myInt = that.mult(i)
     | }
defined class intOverride

scala> val a = myInt(2)
a: myInt = myInt(2)

scala> 2 * a
res1: myInt = myInt(4)
```

Comment: The same solution but now I stuck again because type of I is not Complex. When I try create it as val I = new Complex(0,1). It becomes private and I can't reach it from the main

Comment: In my case the scope of the `*` override is outside of the `Complex` class so you should have access from any object.